# Calendar overlay: Show different events to different people/groups

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, calendar

Is it possible to show different events to different people in an consolidated calendar?

For example:

I have two calendars
- Executive_Calendar
- Employee_Calendar

I combine them in an overlayed calendar. Now executives should see all events from employee and executive calendar. But employees should **only** see events from employee calendar.

Is this achievable in some way?